# content of detail activity shows same thing two times?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, detailsview

While I am developing popular Sunshine android app through udacity course . In lesson three while trying to display content in detailactivity the content shows the same data twice ... not only content but action bar also displays the item twice .so how can this be solved ??

Comment: Could you please get us the code and the errors you are getting if any

Comment: Ok I will .. I am new to stackoverflow so getting some problems ..I am uploading snapshots and codes